# HTTP Libraries for Emacs

Tags: http, emacs

I recently discovered the org-mode in emacs and it works very well for me. I also like www.RememberTheMilk.com. I would like to be able to sync my org-mode file and RTM list. I know that RTM has its API exposed as web services. I am currently looking for a HTTP library that I could use to write my script. I found a couple of links but I am still not entirely satisfied.

http://www.koders.com/lisp/fidB46CCCA8D57FBD093BAF6E08289CFB4DA7624B2B.aspx?s=TV+Raman
http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/http-post-simple.el

Any pointers in doing web service interactions with emacs would be very useful. Also please keep in mind that I'm not a seasoned emacs expert. I have broken the initial barriers of emacs and can find my way around elisp. So, be gentle. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Emacs ships with url.el and url-http.el. Although http-get.el, http-post.el and http-cookies.el are in vogue today. Here's the GitHub link where you can get it from.

http://github.com/wfarr/dotfiles/tree/master/.elisp

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to work on this, I'd use [Pymacs](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/) to interface Emacs to Python and then use the existing [Python API kit](http://repo.or.cz/w/pyrtm.git) for Remember the Milk. Why re-implement all the HTTP crud yourself?